# Can't pull gitlab-runner helper image on ppc64le Rocky Linux with Podman

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, podman, rocky-os, ppc64le

I am trying to run a job on a self hosted gitlab instance, but I am having problems when I want to run the actual job.
The error I get is:
ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:ppc64le-d240d5bb" with specified policies [always]: writing blob: adding layer with blob "sha256:516de0f0c3b2ecd31c2cc1e99b2e94f754a43216a9402bbcf7a9c1f687566820": processing tar file(potentially insufficient UIDs or GIDs available in user namespace (requested 0:42 for /etc/shadow): Check /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid if configured locally and run podman-system-migrate: lchown /etc/shadow: invalid argument): exit status 1 (manager.go:237:4s)

Locally, I can pull and run any container, including the one from the error, but when the job is started through the gitlab web interface, it fails with the above error.
Operating system is Rocky Linux 9.2 on ppc64le architecture and we are using podman.
I have tried many things, including changing the config.toml file with some suggestions from the community, but nothing seems to change the situation, and adding the subuid and subgid for both the gitlab-runner user and root.

Comment: Can you provide your runner configuration? Have you installed `podman-plugins` ?

Comment: @sytech Thanks for commenting :) I ended up completely removing podman and installed and set everything up with docker. Now it works without issues :D